# Unity AddTorque has no effect with values above x?

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-physics, unityscript

As the title states, the value I assign to the Rigid Body seems to have no effect above some value.

I have a root object with a hingejoint assigned. It has the default setting except the axis is set to (0,1,0) and not (1,0,0). No connected body.

It has a rigidbody attached with default values. I have tried many combinations of drag / angular drag. None seem to effect anything.

It has a child gameobject / mesh renderer assigned so I can see it rotate.

Any ideas what is going on?

```
rotorRoot.AddTorque((rotorRoot.transform.up * 50f), ForceMode.Force);
```

//Turns slowly

```
rotorRoot.AddTorque((rotorRoot.transform.up * 5000f), ForceMode.Force);
```

//Turns about 60 rpm (guess)

```
rotorRoot.AddTorque((rotorRoot.transform.up * 500000000f), ForceMode.Force);
```

//Turns about 60 rpm (guess)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is a limit to the maximum rotational velocity, and you can change it!

From the doc page for [`Physics.maxAngularVelocity`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics-maxAngularVelocity.html):

> The default maximum angular velocity permitted for any rigid bodies
>   (default 7). Must be positive.
>
> The angular velocity of rigidbodies is clamped to maxAngularVelocity
>   to avoid numerical instability with fast rotating bodies. Because this
>   may prevent intentional fast rotations on objects such as wheels, you
>   can override this value per rigidbody using
>   [`Rigidbody.maxAngularVelocity`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-maxAngularVelocity.html).
>
> This value is usually changed in Edit->Project Settings->Physics
>   inspector instead of from scripts.